# Python REGEX ignore case at the beginning of the sentence and take the rest

Tags: python, regex, ignore-case

I have this kind of results:

```
ª!è[008:58:049]HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in...
```

And I want to ignore all the beginning characters like `ª!è` and get only: `HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in...` but in a simple regex line.

I tried this: `^[\W0-9]*` but is taking the extended ASCII characters plus the time and is not ignoring it, is doing the opposite...

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you try?  (show us some code..)

Comment: Use `re.sub(r'^[^a-zA-Z]+', '', s)`.

Comment: I tried this: ^[^\W0-9]*HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written.*

Comment: `re.search("(?<=\]).*",tester).group(0)`; where `tester = ª!è[008:58:049]HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get everything after the closing square bracket, no matter what, and skip everything before that you can go with a `match` like this:

```
s = "ª!è[008:58:049]HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in..."
m = re.match(r'^.*?]([\S\s]*)', s)
print(m.group(1))
```

Print's `'HTTP_CLI:0 - Line written in...'`

This expression looks through an arbitrary number of characters before the closing bracket and matches everything after that. The matched group is available with `m.group(1)`